# Polymer: appending a new child throws error

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to connect nodes using SVG in my Polymer app, and to do that I need to dynamically add a `<path>` to my SVG container. Seems pretty straightforward, but Polymer throws the following error:

`"Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed"`

This error happens when Polymer gets loaded twice, but all I'm doing is appending something. I can't figure out what's happening, especially since similar code somewhere else in my app simply works. The offending lines:

```
_connectNodes: function(){
    _.each(this.nodeRelations, function(relation){
      var newPath = document.createElement('path');
      var path = Polymer.dom(this.$.connectionsContainer).appendChild(newPath);
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think here "this" in this line Polymer.dom(this.$.connectionsContainer) refers to each loop function only. So i suggest define "this" reference variable before each loop and use it.